# How can I get the tap time of the textview?

Tags: android

How can I get the tap time of the textview? The method `getLongPressTimeout()` dosen't work.

I want to know if the `TextView` was pressed long?
What method can I use?

Comment: Use OnLongClickListener. More at http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html

Comment: can you make it more clear what are you actually intending to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use an onLongClick listener as follows:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            //process long click action
            return false;
        }
});
```

additional information available from Android documentation:

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html